# Can run program with Mono but not with Visual Studio Mac

Tags: c#, mono, sfml, visual-studio-mac

So I have a C# program that I'm making in Visual Studio Mac 2019. It uses the SFML.Net framework which depends on a dynamic library: `libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib`. Internally, the framework has a method called `sfRenderWindow_createUnicode(...)`. This method uses a `DLLImport` for `CSFML.graphics`. If I run the program in Visual Studio, I get a `DllNotFoundException` with message `csfml-graphics`.

In my global `config` file for Mono, I have a DLL Mapping:

```
<dllmap dll="csfml-graphics" target="libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib" />
```

After adding that, if I run my program in Visual Studio, I still get a `DllNotFoundException`. *However*, the message now says `libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib`. So it's looking for the right library but can't find it? The `.dylib` file is in the same folder as the `.exe`.

The weird part is I *can* run the program from the terminal like so:

```
MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug MONO_LOG_MASK=dll mono hello-csharp.exe > log.txt
```

The `log.txt` file contains the following lines:

```
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib'.
Mono: DllImport loaded library '/Users/rutvik/Desktop/hello-csharp/hello-csharp/bin/Debug/libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib' ('/Users/rutvik/Desktop/hello-csharp/hello-csharp/bin/Debug/libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib').
Mono: Searching for 'sfRenderWindow_createUnicode'.
Mono: Probing 'sfRenderWindow_createUnicode'.
Mono: Found as 'sfRenderWindow_createUnicode'.
```

So it *can* find the `.dylib` for some reason. What is Visual Studio Mac doing differently? And how do I configure it to make it work?

For reference, here is `otool -L` run against `libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib`:

```
libcsfml-graphics.2.5.0.dylib:
    libcsfml-graphics.2.5.dylib (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.0)
    @rpath/sfml-graphics.framework/Versions/2.5.1/sfml-graphics (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
    @rpath/sfml-window.framework/Versions/2.5.1/sfml-window (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
    @rpath/sfml-system.framework/Versions/2.5.1/sfml-system (compatibility version 2.5.0, current version 2.5.1)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)
```

**WHAT WORKED IN THE END:**

Just to summarize, I put all the `.dylib` files in `/usr/local/lib`. The trick was to set the platform target to `x64` as specified in the accepted answer. The `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment actually turned out to be not needed at all. And the `.dylib` files do not have to be in the same folder as the `.exe`.

Now both running from Visual Studio and running with `mono` in the terminal yield identical results.

Hooray!

Comment: you say "If I run the program in VisualStudio...," and later "now, if I run the program in VisualStudio..."; I guess there's a typo somewhere

Comment: @knocte I meant to say that if I run it in Visual Studio _after adding that `<dllmap>`_. I edited my post for clarity, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Make sure your `Platform Target` matches your ABI type (x32 or x64 bit):

[image]

VS4M will launch the 32-bit Mono version by default as most project targets default to `x32`. Of course this does not matter if you are producing "fat" dylibs.

2) Set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your `Run Configuration` to match your dylib location:

[image]

re: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#macos-framework-and-dylib-search-path

Comment: So right now the DLLs are in `bin/Debug`, and when I use the absolute path to that folder, everything works. Is there a way to state more generally to look in the executable folder? I also tried copying the DLLs to `/usr/local/lib` using that for `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but it doesn't work. It doesn't throw an exception, it just seems to freeze and do nothing.

Comment: @rcplusplus I think it is `${TargetPath}` but can not remember if VS4M does the expansion for env. vars. before setting them for that run session (it does for post/pre commands, etc..)

Comment: Ok something just weird has happened. I removed the environment variable from the list and everything still works... The `.dylib` files are in both `bin/Debug` and `/usr/local/lib`. Not sure why everything magically works now??

Comment: I spoke to soon everything has broken again

Comment: Ok, so I created a new project, and now I'm back to the same spot. The `.dylib` files are in `/usr/local/bin/` but NOT in `bin/Debug`. When this is the case, `mono hello-csharp.exe` works perfectly fine, but running in Visual Studio gives `DllNotFoundException`. Here's the kicker, if I copy the `.dylib` files to `bin/Debug` and set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately, I _still_ get `DllNotFoundException`...

Comment: Idiot of the day award should go to me because I forgot to set the platform target. So I've officially gone in a full circle...

Comment: Where is Platform target and Environment Variables?  VS or Xcode?

Comment: @DougNull if you look at the question's tags, it is for macOS. This is for VS4M.

Comment: That was also the reason why why why my breakpoints were not hit. Thank you!